# AWS Django Ec2 step 4 "no how to"

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, virtualenv

So I'm working to deploy my python code to my AWS ec2 instance and at step four of the second part

Create a Django Project... more like creating a waste of your time. Five hours trying to get this setup. Tried seven different setups over the last 3 months.

AWS seems like an overly complicated system setup for enterprise class businesses and they thumb their nose at students trying to learn.

The customer service guy said "go watch youtube training videos" who tells a frustrated potential customer that?

Your salesman came to UW and talked a great game, discounting knowledge to get their product setup vs digitalocean or Heroku.

I tried to post in the AWS forums and I'm not allowed as a registered student developer?

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create-deploy-python-django.html

It says to make a .ebextension file and add stuff to it but it doesn't say how to create a .ebextension file and mac says that files that begin with dots are reserved for system files so am I reading this wrong?

How can I proceed with this "simple server setup" that is neither simple nor setup if its missing info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not .ebextensions file, the link you provided mentioned create a directory called `.ebextensions`, it is a folder name, and you can make it by:

`mkdir .ebextensions`

Then create a configuration file `django.config` in  the folder, it would be 
`~/ebdjango/.ebextensions/django.config`

[image: screenshots from the site you provided, it showed you how to make the folder]